# which version of linux kernel starts to support sd/sdio version 3.00?

Tags: linux, git, kernel, device, linux-device-driver

--Hello there,

Here is a question about linux kernel sd/mmc subsystem.

At present, the version of linux kernel we use is 2.6.29.4.

Now, there is a SD/MMC controller which supports SD/SDIO version 3.00 integrated into the SoC, so, we need to update linux kernel to support SD/SDIO version 3.00.

Does anybody know from which version linux kernel starts to support SD/SDIO version 3.00?

Or, are there any ways to achieve our goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux Kernel version 3.3 starts the support of SD/SDIO version 3.00.

See this commit

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/include/linux/mmc/sdio.h?h=linux-3.3.y&id=b4625dab2c618eb87e177761dda3182b4cfaa604

Kernel 3.3 (found the `SDIO_SD_REV_3_00` define)
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/linux/mmc/sdio.h?h=linux-3.3.y

Kernel 3.2 (NOT found the `SDIO_SD_REV_3_00` define):
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/linux/mmc/sdio.h?h=linux-3.2.y

Comment: Thanks so much,Dudytz.    
I will check it out.  

BTW, do you know if we can just port the SD/MMC subsystem independently without changing any other part of linux kernel?  
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you can always quickly answer to this and similar questions by searching in kernel source. Most useful commands are `git grep` and `git log -S<symbol>`.

Just clone kernel source code:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
cd linux
```

and then run command like this to find what you want:

```
git log -SSDIO_SD_REV_3_00
```

Which gives following result (just one commit!):

```
commit a303c5319c8e6ab0e744ebca118da8420043b2c3
Author: Philip Rakity <prakity@marvell.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 14 19:14:38 2011 -0800

mmc: sdio: support SDIO UHS cards

This patch adds support for sdio UHS cards per the version 3.0
spec.
...
```

Now, you can use git describe to get kernel version closest to that commit:

```
git describe --contains a303c5319c8e6ab0e744ebca118da8420043b2c3
```

which prints:

```
v3.3-rc1~72^2~51
```

In other words, it became official in kernel version 3.3.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details.
This is a so good a method to find focused keyword in Linux kernel.